# How do you get the *slime-source* buffer to appear?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

I was doing something in SLIME, and an error occurred. While trying to select the ABORT restart, I made a typo, and instead of the debugger closing, a new buffer named `*slime-source*` appeared. It contained a LAMBDA form with the expression I'd typed at the REPL, pretty-printed.

This is potentially useful, but I don't know how I did it. What did I type to make this buffer appear?

Comment: Option 'v' from this document? https://www.cliki.net/slime%20features

Comment: Yeah, that's it.

Comment: If you act quickly, you can ask Emacs to show you what you typed recently with `view-lossage` - do `C-h f view-lossage` for more info and key bindings.